# Foundation 6 offcanvas toggle jumps to top

Tags: zurb-foundation-6, off-canvas-menu

Goodmorning,
I wonder if there is a way to prevent Foundation 6's toggle off-canvas from jumping to the top of the page. I notice that this behaviour is also present in [official F6 documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html)

Comment: I tried passing the option forceTop to the plugin, but it doesn't work.
var foo = new Foundation.OffCanvas($('#offCanvas'));
foo.options.forceTop = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution. In foundation 6, off-canvas options "forceTop" is currently disabled. If you don't want this behaviour, just go to

bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.offcanvas.js

and comment, at line 211

$('body').scrollTop(0);

The rebuild all the assets.

Hope this helps

EDIT
If you wish, it was fixed in development version, and you can grab the correct file. Or you can just add

if ( this.options.forceTop ) { $('body').scrollTop(0); }

to yours in order to restore forceTop option.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just use `data-force-top=false` in your div attributes as below:

```
<div class="off-canvas position-right" id="offCanvasRight" data-force-top=false data-off-canvas data-position="right">
```